# Google Maps : OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I'm a beginner in Google Maps and I've been looking at the OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier Github instructions, but after a couple of hours of fiddling around, I couldn't get anything to works! My code is pretty simple, as I'm just in the process of learning. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      </style>
      <script src="http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/bin/oms.min.js"></script> //added the file
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script> 

    function initialize() {
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
      var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map); //Spiderfied it here
      var iw = new gm.InfoWindow();
      oms.addListener('click', function(marker, event) {
        iw.setContent(marker.desc);
        iw.open(map, marker);
      });
      oms.addListener('spiderfy', function(markers) {
        iw.close();
      });

      var locations = ["Sydney, Australia", "Sydney, Australia", "Sydney, Australia", "Sydney, Australia"]

      for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i ++) {
        var title_i = "title " + i;
        var desc_i = "description " + i;
        var loc = new gm.LatLng(-35.3080, 149.1245);
        var marker = new gm.Marker({
          position: loc,
          title: title_i,
          map: map
        });
        marker.desc = desc_i;
        oms.addMarker(marker);  // <-- here attempted to add markers
      } 
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's very similar to the code on the Github, but unfortunately, I still can't get it to work. I started off with messing with geocoding and integrating it with customizable markers (like different color markers), but I just can't get the Open Spiderfier running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues:

1. you must first load the maps-API, and then the `oms.min.js`
2. you've ommitted this part: `var gm=google.maps;` . Put it to the begin of `initialize()`

Comment: Could I ask another question?

Comment: @user3758332 you can certainly ask another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask